# Continuous colour symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a vector layer with values ranging between 0 and 1 in the field I want to plot. I choose `Graduated` symbology type and a colour ramp. But then it seems to me like you have to divide your values into classes. I can choose `Pretty Breaks` and type in a high number of classes, like 100, and it all works out, but it seems like an inefficient way to do it. Am I doing it wrong? Is there no option to let QGIS associate each value with a hue along the colour ramp continuously? E.g. if the value of a feature is 0.387 it should be coloured with the hue lying at 38.7% the length of the colour ramp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `Mode` to `Equal Interval`, than you get what you want (this also works for the legend):

---

Another option if you want to avoid creating categories (like when using `Graduated symbology`), but instead want the color to be selected continuously from a colour ramp, is to set the color to data driven override and select `Assistant`.

In the Assistant, select the source (an attribute field or expression), load Values from / to and select a color ramp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this basically does the same as `Pretty Breaks`, and it does work for sure. I was just thinking that it seems a bit excessive, even with as many as 100 classes you only get accuracy by integer percent. A continuous scale without classes, correlating the exact percentage with `ramp_color(ramp_name, the_same_percentage)` as @Al rl suggested, would have been much more efficient.

Comment: OK, data driven override seems to be the other possibility to do what you want, see edited solution.

Comment: That's the thing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way to get a more gradual rendering but you wouldn't be able to use the legend symbols directly. You'd probably need to make a mock ramp (an expty raster with the symbology to populate the legend).

As for the vector layer itself, using data-defined symbology you can use the [ramp-color](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#ramp-color) function to get the color value, just need to use the name of the ramp you want and scale the values them between 0 and 1 .

Comment: What do you mean by data-defined symbology? How do I use that?

Comment: Alright, @Babel got there first and sorted it all out :)